# Issue with Identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a table with identity column set to (1,1). I need to delete rows everytime a file comes in and load the data from the file. So in my process daily I need to :-

1. delete all the records from the table A
2. Execute DBCC ('table', reseed, 0)
3. Insert new records in table  A

Problem: Each time I insert new records to table A, the identity column starts with 57.

I need to start with 1. Can anyone be able to help with this?

Note: I cannot use truncate because of permission issue. And I delete all the records each time.

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Reseeding resets it. Maybe your rights aren't enough so DBCC fails too?

Comment: Truncate is not allowed. :)

Comment: If you can't `TRUNCATE` due to permissions then I doubt you can use DBCC to reseed, as @siggemannen suggests. You should talk to your DBA for those permissions, or perhaps automate the task with an account that does. `TRUNCATE` appears to be the right tool for the job here.

Comment: you can also probably use set insert_identity ON to force specific identity on the inserts

Comment: If you check the [relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), you'll note that `DBCC CHECKIDENT` requires *higher* permissions than `TRUNCATE` and if you have permission to use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` you have high enough to use `TRUNCATE`. So use `TRUNCATE`...

Answer (score 0):

After getting the records deleted.
You can set the Identity Insert on:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <yourtable> ON
```

While inserting, you can SELECT the required columns, with additional column with ROW_NUMBER() e.g.:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, OtherColumns
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: what about constraints ? you will break PK,FK constraints, indexes and so on.

Comment: That problem already exists due to the OP's `DELETE` @jmvcollaborator , so likely there isn't any keys involved.

Comment: Still not able to figure out why identity column always starts with 57 after delete and reseeding.

Comment: perhaps you have some rollback going on?